# Web Design - Modal CSS Change to Display Block on Site Exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement an easy way of displaying a **small modal window when the user exits my Website**, containing a quick and easy single question dialog, with a multiple-choice answer, and a submit button..

I'm having trouble finding a simple, straight-forward answer everywhere I've looked. Yes, I searched.

**NOTE: I already have my Modal Window created, with the Form on it, and everything ready! (currently the Modal Window is set to Display None, until I figure out the following question)..**

What I need to know exactly is this: **What is the easiest way to simply detect when the user is leaving my website, and set the Property of the Modal Window ID  to Display:Block for example, which would change it from Display:None and make it show?**

I would prefer a simple script being able to detect any of the following behavior as they are trying to exit the website either by (A) clicking X on the tab, (B) clicking X on the window, or (C) hitting the back button enough times to leave my Site - at which time, the script would change my Modal's ID property from display none, to display block.. Thats it.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Not possible without a real modal window. All the emulated modals are asynchronous, and the page will be closed after the synchronous part of JS has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a special event for this `onbeforeunload`

```
<script>
  window.onbeforeunload = exitFunc;
  function exitFunc() {
    modal logic here
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I appreciate the straight-forward answer and info! However I do have a couple of questions about the 'onbeforeunload' event you mentioned..

Firstly, I admittedly am not very well-versed when it comes to JavaScript.. So what exactly would the Modal Logic part of the code be? For the sake of writing a complete code, lets just say that my currently-hidden (Display None) Modal's ID name is "modalname", and the CSS file (if needed) that contains the Modal's CSS is named "cssfile.css".. How would the full code look? I very much appreciate the help!